# How do I avoid significant rounding error in evaluating $(\ln(x) - \sin(\pi x))(1-x)^{-1}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation, numerical-calculus, truncation-error, significant-figures

How do I avoid significant rounding error in evaluating $$\frac{\ln(x) - \sin(\pi x) }{1-x}$$

This function causes error as $x\to 1$. How can this be avoided? I tried using taylor's expansion but I am not getting a nice closed form. Please help

Comment: Hint: For $x$ close to $1$, $$\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0, \text{ even}} (-1)^{n/2}\frac{\pi^{n+1} (x-1)^n}{(n+1)!}$$ So your function has the Taylor expansion $$-\pi +(x-1)+\frac{1}{6} \left(\pi ^3-3\right) (x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3}
   (x-1)^3+\left(-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\pi ^5}{120}\right) (x-1)^4+\frac{1}{5}
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$ around $1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do the two terms in the numerator separately.

$$\frac{\log(x)}{1-x} \approx -1+\frac 12(x-1)-\frac 13(x-1)^2+\frac 14(x-1)^3+\ldots$$ from the usual Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$

$\sin(\pi x)$ goes to zero, canceling the zero in the denominator.  The limit of the second term as $x \to 1$ is $\pi.\ \ $  We can just use the Taylor series, defining $y=1-x$ and expanding around $y=0$
$$\frac {\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}=\frac{\sin(\pi(1-y))}y=\frac {\sin(\pi y)}y\approx \pi-\frac 16(\pi y)^2+\frac 1{120}(\pi y)^4+\ldots$$

Comment: There was a typo in post but nice concept. I know how to solve now

Comment: @gt6989b yes true.